# Swift Package Manager extracting BinaryPackage

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am reading some articles about SwiftPackageManager and wanted to create a Logger package for my application. I successfully managed to run my package into an example application with a default target specification

```
.target(
    name: "Logger",
    dependencies: [])
```

However, I wanted to distribute my package as binary and see what's happening, then I added .binaryTarget as you can see below in Package.swift file. I created a folder named `artifacts` and would like to wait for my package will be extracted.

```
import Foundation

public struct Logger {
   public static var `default` = Logger()

   public static private(set) var text = "Hello, World!"

   public init() {}

   public func log(_ printed: String) {
      print(printed)
   }

   public func getTitle() -> String {
       NSLocalizedString("", tableName: nil, bundle: .module, value: "title", comment: "")
   }
```

}

The code which is above is just as its and here is my `Package` file.

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.6
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Logger",
    defaultLocalization: "es",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Logger",
            targets: ["Logger"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "Logger",
            path: "artifacts/Logger.xcframework"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "LoggerTests",
            dependencies: ["Logger"]),
    ]
)
```

However I get the error  `There is no XCFramework found at '/Users/user/Desktop/Logger/artifacts/Logger.xcframework'.`
I do not understand at all, why Xcode waits for `.xcframework` in the artifacts folder, should it extract to this path already? Even if I specify the path like

```
path: "Logger.xcframework"),
```

the same error occurs, so I did not understand the situation here. Should I create xcframework manually? (It does not sense correct because package manager should extract the binary package)

How can I extract my SwiftPackage as a binary package in this situation locally?

Thanks